# Custom post ui plugin & WP_Query - Polylang

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, plugin-polylang

I used to have a multilingual website translated with Qtranslate but now I am changing this to Polylang. I had a wp_query (below) that was working fine and when converted to polylang shows that no posts match my criteria

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'conversatietafel',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'category_name' => 'Volwassene',
  'public' => True,
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Categories and posts are translated and found in Polylang.

I'm not very good in coding, my excuse for this.

Kind regards,
Xavier

Comment: Does this post type still exist or was this something created by QTranslate?  `'post_type' => 'conversatietafel',`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,

changed post_type once to 'post' and than back to 'conversatietafel' and now he is showing the posts !

Sorry to bother :s